# how to include globals.php in template.php file

Tags: theming

I need the variables from the globals.php and I can't seem to call/register them in theme's template.php file. These variables are needed for my custom hook function for the template. Am i missing something (since it's been global and be called somewhere else during rendering)?

Comment: so far I used global keyword in php, is there something that calls the whole file/module itself and all its settings and variables?

Comment: What's `globals.php`? Is that a custom file in your project? The way to include files in PHP is with the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function

Comment: the globals.php i think is included in 7, refer to here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/7 , and yes I tried 'include' but I assume that it is included through rendering the page but the scope of the variable is limited

Comment: Ah ok, that's not a physical file just a dev doc that's where I got confused. To access global vars outside the global context (i.e. in a function) you need to 'import' them, e.g. `global $user; echo $user->name;`

Comment: ok, yeah thanks for this... i'm trying my best not to mess up the drupal core files so i'm trying to use hooks

Answer (score 0):

1.in order to include entire file into some other file,we have 2 functions in php:-

a) include('filename'):this function will include the file and if any error occurs during the importing of the file,then the script will not stop and will continue with its execution.

b) require('filename'):this function will include the file and if any error occurs during the importing of the file,then the script will stop.

include() function is recommended for including files.

Comment: thanks for this, but i'm asking here in a drupal 'way' of including the files, and yes i consider include but I guess drupal already called the file but the variables isn't global in scope, i tried to avoid that since it would be kind of redundant, is there some way to include/load module without calling the file again, just the variables?